# Use default run configuration for Cucumber JS

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumberjs

I have one folder with two sets of Cucumber JS tests

```
- js-tests
  - api
  - component
  - node_modules
  ...
```

This folder contains one instance of Cucumber JS and then I'm using run configurations to specify which Cucumber JS test suites to run.

Here's the component test run configuration (I've removed absolute paths for brevity and secrecy, they all exist):

[image]

The API test run configuration is the same, just replacing `component` with `api`.

Everything is fine when I run all tests for a given suite from the play button at the top of IntelliJ:
[image]

I can swap between component and API tests there. However, when I click the play button in the gutter of specific test, it uses the default configuration template (not the api or component test templates).

Is there any way to specify which template I want to use for these gutter runs? I've disabled the creation of temporary configurations (by setting it to 0) but running the gutter tests changes the configuration template to `current file`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you start an individual test by clicking a gutter icon, the IDE auto-creates a new run configuration unless a configuration associated with this particular test exists. This new configuration is based on a run configuration [template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2023.1/run-debug-configuration.html#templates), existing run configurations can't be used for it. So I can only suggest modifying the template accordingly